# WPF DataGrid и SizeToContent

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Мозг уже сломал.

Есть Window с `WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"`

Внутри есть `DataGrid` с колонками, где последняя колонка имеет `Width="*"` чтобы заполнить всю ширину таблицы.

Нужно чтобы при открытии окна таблица отображала весь контент, но не шире экрана и при этом позволяла себя дальше ресайзить.

Наблюдения:

1. Если у Window сделать `SizeToContent="Width"`, то при открытии окна левая часть окна получается посередине экрана, а правая распахивается за пределы экрана с шириной окна. Видимо сначала срабатывает "размести меня в центре" и при этом ширина окна 0, а потом идет расчет и заполнение доступного пространства и правая часть улетает на всю ширину.
2. Если `SizeToContent="Manual"`, то ширина таблицы ровно такая какая задана и полностью игнорирует ширину контента при открытии (ресайзить конечно можно потом)

То есть нужен вменяемый `SizeToContent="Width"` у таблицы/окна и не вылезать за пределы экрана, да и по центру быть.

Comment: Ну в крайнем случае, раз автоматика не справляется, можно подсчитать нужные размеры в code behind?

Comment: А ещё, нельзя ли привязать `MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ваше_окно}"`?

Comment: @VladD MaxWidth не сработает, потому что он всего лишь запрещает * тянуться больше ширины окна (но это ведь так и происходит. таблица не шире окна, просто окно от центра и за пределами экрана). SizeToContent не знает размера таблицы. Таблица не знает своего размера из-за *, а MaxWidth ничего не решает. В итоге просто получаем анимацию распахивания окна от центра когда вся эта кучка друг друга пересчитывает. А code-behind...я банально не знаю что там считать ведь я не знаю ширины контента.

Comment: @VladD я так понимаю надо писать атачед или даже свой контрол где посчитать суму всех колонок (для этого последнюю выставить не в * а в auto), выставить размер контрола и последнюю колонку ширину заменить на *. Только не понимаю куда вклиниваться со всей этой логикой.

Comment: Если вручную совсем, то надо переопределять `MeasureOverride` и `ArrangeOverride`.

Comment: @VladD А если не вручную, а на событии контроллоадед будет ли уже просчитаны размеры колонок, чтобы от них отталкиваться? А то визуально окно отображается и потом начинает бежать вправо. а с MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth это выглядит как анимация даже

Comment: По идее да, но это может быть слишком поздно. Ну и вам всё равно нужно ещё что-то делать, если размер окна поменяет юзер.